# Short Integer Solution Problem what does nlogq mean?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography

I have a question about SIS problem, please check it;
[basic definition of sis problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGFCF.png)

my question is Where do we find the nlogq what does nlogq mean ?

thank you for all

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not about programming.

Comment: I didn't say it's about programming anyway

Comment: hence not suitable in this forum. Try https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: my question is about post-quantum-cryptograhy